How to Get Slug in Server-Side Layout in Next.js Component?
I am trying to pass a slug to a server-side function in my Next.js layout component. My slug is returning undefined, and I need to find a way to correctly grab and utilize the slug on the server side within the layout file. Despite using getServerSideProps to fetch the slug in my page component, it seems the slug is not making its way to the layout component. I suspect there might be an issue with how I'm attempting to pass the slug as a prop or perhaps with the overall structure of my code. Is there a proper method to capture the slug on the server side specifically in a layout file in Next.js? Here is my code:
import { Metadata } from "next";
import { fetchMetadata } from "@/lib/fetch-meta-data";
import { lora, poppins } from "@/app/fonts";

type Params = {
  slug: string;
};

type SearchParams = {
  [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined;
};

type Props = {
  params: Params;
  searchParams: SearchParams;
};

export async function generateMetadata({ params }: Props): Promise<Metadata> {
  const { slug } = params;

  console.log(params, "Log params in generateMetadata");
  const pageMetadata = await fetchMetadata(slug);

  const defaultTitle = "Default App Name";
  const defaultDescription =
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
  const defaultImageUrl = `/images/default.jpg`;
  const pageTitle = pageMetadata?.title
    ? `${pageMetadata.title} | App Name`
    : defaultTitle;

  return {
    title: pageTitle,
    description: pageMetadata?.description || defaultDescription,
    keywords: pageMetadata?.keywords || "default, keywords",
    applicationName: "App Name",
    authors: [{ name: "App Name" }],
    publisher: "App Name",
    formatDetection: {
      email: false,
      address: false,
      telephone: false,
    },
    openGraph: {
      title: pageMetadata?.title || defaultTitle,
      description: pageMetadata?.description || defaultDescription,
      url: `/path/${slug}`,
      siteName: "App Name",
      images: [
        {
          url: pageMetadata?.imageUrl || defaultImageUrl,
          width: 1200,
          height: 630,
        },
      ],
      locale: "en_US",
      type: "website",
    },
    twitter: {
      card: "summary_large_image",
      title: pageMetadata?.title || defaultTitle,
      description: pageMetadata?.description || defaultDescription,
      images: [pageMetadata?.imageUrl || defaultImageUrl],
    },
    robots: {
      index: true,
      follow: true,
    },
  };
}

export default function ServerLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html
      lang="en-US"
      suppressHydrationWarning
      className={`${poppins.variable} ${lora.variable}`}
    >
      <body suppressHydrationWarning>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}

This file is my server-layout inside of my components/layouts folder.  This file gets called in my layout.tsx file inside of my app directory.
This is my app layout code:
// app/layout.tsx
import ServerLayout, {
  generateMetadata,
} from "@/components/layouts/main/server-layout";
import ClientLayout from "@/components/layouts/main/client-layout";

export default function AppLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <ServerLayout>
      <ClientLayout>{children}</ClientLayout>
    </ServerLayout>
  );
}

export { generateMetadata };


Where are you invoking generateMetadata()? Add a [mre] so that we know how arguments are being passed to generateMetadata().

I'm invoking generateMetadata to add meta data fields to my pages in Next 14

We believe you. We just need to know how the invocation is done.

Why the downvote? This seems like a genuine question.

It's handled automatically with the framework.  I'm not sure how it picks it up and yes, this is a genuine question

Do you mind sharing the file structure? Layouts can certainly receive dynamic path slugs but they need to be inside said slug folder. If this is the root layout, you would have to refactor it so that you can extract whatever logic needs to be done with the slug into another layout.

@moonstar-x I have added the structure

generateMetadata() still gets exported by app/layout.tsx. So where does it get invoked? Just keep tracing it.

@ChukwujiobiCanon Those are the only two places in my code base with reference to generateMetadata.  The function is async and is fired in my server-layout.ts file.

Do this from within generateMetadata(): console.log(__dirname).

@ChukwujiobiCanon generateMetadata() is a special export in Next.js that pages and layouts can leverage for metadata generation at build time. There is no explicit call to this function in the project's codebase as its used directly by Next.js when building the application.

As I was writing an answer for this I came to realize that, your generateMetadata function should probably be inside app/[slug]/page.tsx and not in a layout since you're defining the metadata. Wouldn't that make more sense?

@moonstar-x That makes sense if you want to have to do it for every page, but it does not make sense if you want to set it up to be a global component. Essentially I want to read the page path and then fetch the corresponding meta data from my db and then load that on the layout so that I don't have to add generateMetadata to all my pages.

I see, wouldn't it be better in this case to abstract away the metadata computation and just have a generateMetadata on your pages reusing your abstraction? The alternative would be to re-organize your app folder with empty layouts.

@moonstar-x yeah that is what I am doing because I don't see a more simple approach

Share your folder structure and the URL you are invoking that causes this. I think I have a solution now. @moonstar-x I completely missed that part thank you.

actually layout components in Next.js do not directly receive the same props as page components.
You can check the solution to using slugs in layout component here

So after seeing where your components are located I can say that:

Your ServerLayout component is technically not a Next.js Layout because the filename must be layout.tsx or layout.ts.
Since your ServerLayout component is neither a page or a layout technically, the generateMetadata function does not get called anywhere.
ServerLayout has no way to identify what the dynamic path slug is called because its file is not inside a dynamic path folder. In your case, since you're naming this parameter slug, the layout should be inside app/[slug].

Keep in mind that route resolution is done by folder structure. You can also leverage route groups to group up pages that will use your layouts without adding anything onto the route.

Given this, how about keeping a folder structure similar to this?
.
├── app/
│   ├── [slug]/
│   │   ├── layout.tsx
│   │   └── page.tsx
│   ├── layout.tsx
│   └── page.tsx
└── components/
    └── layouts/
        └── main/
            ├── server-layout.tsx
            └── client-layout.tsx

We can keep ServerLayout inside components/layouts/main/server-layout.tsx so long as we treat it as a regular React component.
Now, inside the file app/[slug]/layout.tsx you can include the generateMetadata() function and a passthrough component that returns children directly.
Basically something like:
app/[slug]/layout.tsx:
export const generateMetadata = () => {
  return //my metadata;
}

export default PassthroughLayout = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  return children;
}

This way, any page that is a descendent of app/[slug] will share this generateMetadata definition.

This framework sucks. Route resolution by folder structure? I couldn’t disagree more. Who even came up with this crap? Probably functions will also only be recognized by the name of the module they are contained in. Bad design! Bad design at best!!

For anyone that is looking to solve this, the best way to do it is to add the pathname as a header using your middleware so that then you can get the header value inside of your layout components.
